# Upgrade a site from 8.5.13 to 9

Tags: 9, upgrading

I've an old Drupal 8.5.x site. There are too many custom and contributed modules. We need to update the site to latest version of modules, Drupal core, and Composer.

What is the ideal way to approach the upgrade?
Should I directly try Composer 2 and require Drupal 9?
Should I update the code base in batches?
Should I do something else?

It also uses JSONAPI as contributed module, which is now a Drupal core module.
Is it fine to run `composer remove drupal/jsonapi` before updating Drupal core?
Should I be worried about its content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I've an older drupal 8 site in 8.5.x version. There are too many custom & contrib modules, eg acquia/blt, lightening, etc.*

OK, there is no simple answer to this. Check the Acquia site how to proceed with their no longer supported products.

But I'm trying to answer the other questions:

*We need to update the site to latest, modules, core, etc. It uses Composer 1. What is the ideal way to approach the upgrade?*

Keep Composer 1 until you have finished the update process and by doing this remove any packages which don't work with Composer 2.

*Should I directly try composer 2 and require drupal 9 or should I update the codebase in batches? eg first update to 8.9.20 and then to 9.x?*

You need to update to the latest Drupal 8 first and run `update.php`. This is in the release notes of Drupal 9. The reason is they removed older Drupal 8 update hooks and if you would update directly to Drupal 9 without running update.php on the latest Drupal 8 you are missing those update hooks and you can't get rid of the error message on the Status page no matter how often you are running the update script.

*It also uses jsonapi as a contrib module which i see is now merged to core drupal. Is it fine to simple composer remove drupal/jsonapi before update drupal/core? Should i be worried about its contents?*

JSON API doesn't have content and there is not much to configure. So you should be fine with un-installing the contrib module in Drupal before you remove it with Composer and then enable the core module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is `run update.php` same as `drush updb`?

Comment: `drush help updb`: Apply any database updates required (as with running update.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't read it yet, here is the official documentation for upgrading from D8 to D9 : https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/how-to-prepare-your-drupal-7-or-8-site-for-drupal-9/upgrading-a-drupal-8-site

To summarize:

- Update your core to the latest 8.x version (8.9.20)
- Update your contrib modules and dependencies to the latest compatible version and ensure these modules are compatible with D9 core (some may not be maintained anymore, for instance)
- Update your custom modules and themes to be compatible with Drupal 9 (I recommend you to use [Upgrade status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status) module to help you)
- Once you are done and your website runs smoothly, you may require the 9.x core.

It may be a cumbersome process, but if you respect the steps order, everything should go well.

Good luck :-)